# Accurev Post Promote Trigger

Tags: accurev

I need email notification for each checkins in Accurev.
I am not sure how do i configure it. I heard about post promote trigger.
Could you please tell me the path and how to configure the post promote trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the file called server_post_promote.pl under "accurev install directory/examples".

Inside this file are details regarding how to configure/install this trigger.

All you need to do is add the email logic into the script once a promote occurs into a stream.